# Field label and page layout updates

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, metadata

I've made an update to a field label and I also updated few page layouts. Assignments have not changed for different profiles.

Now I need to deploy these changes from one sandbox to another. Do I need to deploy field label update along with page layouts or deploying layouts will be sufficient?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deploy the field and page layouts together. Page layouts have field names in the actual metadata file. They pull the field labels using the API name of the field from the org. To reflect the new label in the target org, the field must also be deployed.

An example of how a field is stored in page layout with a field label 'Date Submitted' and API name `Date_Submitted__c`

```
        <layoutItems>
            <behavior>Required</behavior>
            <field>Date_Submitted__c</field>
        </layoutItems>
```

Comment: does that mean I need to deploy all of the fields that are in the layout or just the one that I updated?

Comment: just the ones that are updated.